# How can I assign a URL with a fragment (#) as an array value?

Tags: forms

In my form:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'mypage/' . $nid . '#comment-form';
```

redirects to:

```
/mypage/1%23comment-form
```

...so it doesn't jump to the comment form. I tried:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = l('', "mypage/$nid", array('fragment' => 'comment-form');
```

...that retuned a bigger mess. I need to link to:

```
/mypage/1#comment-form
```

Basically, I'm trying to jump to the bottom of the page the user is redirected to.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array for `$form_state['redirect']`, the elements of which mirror the arguments passed to the [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) function.

So you can use...

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  "mypage/$nid",
  array('fragment' => 'comment-form'),
);
```

The method it used quite sparingly in core (just 5 occurrences as far as I can tell); [`node_form_delete_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_delete_submit/7) contains an example.